# How to save values to properties without deleting unmodified keys?

Tags: java, properties

So if we do like this:

```
 Properties props = new Properties();
 OutputStream osr = new FileOutputStream(Store.class.getResource("my.properties").getFile());

 props.setProperty("wallboard_text_rgb", "aaa");
 props.setProperty("wallboard_back_rgb", "bbb");

 props.store(osr, "");
```

other keys in existing properties will be deleted, how to avoid that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load properties from that file before modifying it. In other words, replace

```
Properties props = new Properties();
```

with

```
Properties props = Properties.load(new FileInputStream(Store.class.getResource("my.properties").getFile()));
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use

```
String filename = Store.class.getResource("my.properties").getFile();
OutputStream osr = new FileOutputStream(filename, true); // append.
```

If you don't want to keep appending to the file, you have to read all the existing values and re-write them.  Unfortunately properties don't preserve order, or comments, blanks lines etc.